# How can I print all unused elements?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time-complexity

Let's suppose I am holding an array whose size is `n`, and that I have defined a function called `add(i)` which increases the value of the element in index `i` by one.

How may I print all elements whose value is `0` (Haven't even been increased) In `O(k)` where `k` is the number of those elements?

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should use a standard container and iterators.  Some containers have specialized search functions.  There are also standard search functions that use iterators.  Just make sure that your container's iterator types (e.g. random) match the type required by the search function.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `for`-loop man!

Comment: Please show some real code. `k is the number of those elements?` "those elements" refer to all elements or only to elements that haven't been increased?

Comment: Wait a second. K is the number of 0 elements or k is the number of elements over all? The first is actually going to be tricky.

Comment: Maybe `std::transform` could be used?  I recommend reviewing the functions in `<algorithm>` include/header.

Comment: @user4581301 I read it as "where `k` is the number of those elements [whose value is `0`]".

Comment: Are you required to use an array *of integers*? Are you allowed to use an auxiliary data structure? I don't see how one could drop the complexity below O(size of array) without increasing the memory consumption (the classic time-space trade-off).

Comment: @JaMiT that's what I'm worried about. Tricky to do. Need to sacrifice some space complexity to pull it off.

Comment: I want to build my own algorithm and data structure, by k I mean the number of elements whom I want to print, in other words all elements who have changed

Comment: Your comment is the _opposite_ of your base question. In question, you want elements that have _not_ changed (i.e. have a 0 value). But, in comment, you want elements that _have_ changed (i.e. have a non-zero value). Which do you really want? The 2nd one is a bit easier to do.

Comment: When doing `add(i)`, can we assume that `i` is always increasing? That is, we do: `add(1); add(3); add(7);` but _never_ `add(3); add(1); add(7)`?

Comment: Does the final list have to come out in sorted order? Or, can it come out in whatever order the `add` calls are done?

Answer (score 2):

You can't with your current data structure.

There are many options.

- You could use a dictionary of arrays keyed by values. (Then it's just a question of iterating through the array of k elements found at key `0`.)
- You could place all the elements with value zero first or last.
- You could even avoid placing the elements with value zero in the array at all, keeping track of how many there are.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity depends on the size of the input, not the specific details of what that input is. You can't have anything O(k) where k is calculated by iterating over n (assuming k<n). The actual work done would be O(n).

Therefore, we can deduce that you must maintain a completely separate piece of metadata, which is a collection of all indexes which have not yet been incremented. You can output a collection of size k in O(k) ... pretty much by definition.

We are ignoring the work that goes into maintaining that information in the implementation of add(i), because you just asked for O(k) to print the metadata, not to gather it in the first place. Apparently it was a trick question.

Comment: I didn't understand, you are telling me to save all those indexes aside but when one gets changed how may I remove it in O(1)?

Comment: You can PRINT the collection of size k in O(k). As I already said, the amount of work that goes into maintaining it is not what was asked, and therefore irrelevant. Also fundamentally unknowable because we have no indication how many times add() was called.

Comment: Complexity is a measure of how something scales as you increase something. That something can be anything, not necessarily the size of the array. O(k) is perfectly fine.

Comment: @WhiteForce yes, presumably a set. But since add(i) gets called an unknown number of times, you do not know how many that was. But they didn't ask for that, they just asked about printing the k indexes.

Comment: OP needs a special container, like a interval-map, like BOOST::icl::Interval_Map. It's impossible to do exactly what they're looking for with a simple array.

Comment: Yes, That's what I've been saying all along. Except technically, they can satisfy the requirements with a really inefficient container for the k-index, as long as it can iterate in O(k). I didn't want to go into exactly how I would implement it.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* This is based upon your top comment about wanting the print the "changed" indexes (vs. the "unchanged/zero" indexes in your question).

This can be done in `O(k)` time complexity with `O(2n)` space complexity.

Given the original array `arr[n]`, we need an extra array to keep track of the the `k` changed indexes.

Anyway, here's the code with a random test suite:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

enum {
    n = 100
};

int opt_s;                              // 0=unsorted, 1=qsort, 2=insertion
int opt_v;                              // verbose/debug printing
int opt_n;                              // number of array elements
int seed;                               // random seed

// node to keep track of changed indexes
// NOTE: next is only needed for sort mode 2
typedef struct node node_t;
struct node {
    int idx;
    node_t *next;
};

int *arr;                               // original array
node_t *nzlist;                         // list of changed indexes
int k;                                  // number of changed indexes
node_t *head;                           // head of list (sort mode 2)

void
add(int i)
{
    int oval = arr[i]++;
    node_t *newnode;
    node_t *cur;
    node_t *prev;

    do {
        if (oval)
            break;

        if (opt_v)
            printf("add: k=%d i=%d\n",k,i);

        newnode = &nzlist[k++];
        newnode->idx = i;

        if (opt_s != 2)
            break;

        // find sorted insertion point
        prev = NULL;
        for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
            if (cur->idx > i)
                break;
            prev = cur;
        }

        newnode->next = cur;

        // empty list -- set the head
        if (prev == NULL)
            head = newnode;

        // insert before cur
        else
            prev->next = newnode;
    } while (0);
}

int
sortcmp(const void *vplhs,const void *vprhs)
{
    const node_t *lhs = vplhs;
    const node_t *rhs = vprhs;
    int cmpflg;

    cmpflg = lhs->idx - rhs->idx;

    return cmpflg;
}

void
sortlist(void)
{

    qsort(nzlist,k,sizeof(node_t),sortcmp);
}

void
print_link(void)
{
    node_t *cur;

    for (cur = head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        printf("%d\n",cur->idx);
}

void
print_linear(void)
{
    node_t *cur;

    for (cur = &nzlist[0];  cur < &nzlist[k];  ++cur)
        printf("%d\n",cur->idx);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch(cp[-1]) {
        case 'n':
            opt_n = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 300;
            break;

        case 's':
            opt_s = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;

        case 'R':
            seed = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 0;
            break;

        case 'v':
            opt_v = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (opt_n <= 0)
        opt_n = 20;
    printf("n = %d\n",opt_n);
    arr = calloc(opt_n,sizeof(*arr));
    nzlist = calloc(opt_n,sizeof(*nzlist));

    if (seed == 0)
        seed = time(NULL);
    printf("R = %d\n",seed);
    srand(seed);

    int rounds = rand() % (opt_n / 2);
    for (int iround = 0;  iround < rounds;  ++iround) {
        int idx = rand() % opt_n;
        add(idx);
    }

    switch (opt_s) {
    case 0:  // unsorted
        print_linear();
        break;

    case 1:  // sorted by qsort
        sortlist();
        print_linear();
        break;

    case 2:  // insertion sort in linked list
        print_link();
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```